# What's the difference between $10\%$ of $10\text{ cm}$ and $1\text{ cm}$?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, statistics

I overhead a physics professor at my university on the phone:

> *I interviewed that student you sent me, but he didn't know the difference between increasing the length of a $10\text{ cm}$ rod by $1\text{ cm}$ versus by $10\%$, so I didn't accept him into the program.*

Is this some sort of trick question? What difference could he possibly be talking about? A philosophical one?

Comment: Seems like a nit-pick and a rather assinine way do distiguish who should be accepted to the physics program.

Comment: Probably the correct answer was "no difference", but the student didn't knew it (or panicked and didn't tell it)

Comment: One is relative, the other absolute.

Comment: Ah, yes! This must be what the professor was fishing for: Relative vs Absolute! Quite a nitpick, but typical for a physics professor. More than just the simple math, it borders on the philosophical. I'll bet this is it!

Comment: Why 'no way'? Probing to see if a prospective student can think multimodally 'outside the box', in this case, to see if he can view a physics problem in relative or absolute terms (or both), makes total sense.

Comment: Was it maybe meant 'the other way around'? If the professor asked the student what reducing the length of an 11cm rod by 10% means, 1cm would indeed be the wrong answer. To obscure this even more he could have asked what happened if the length of a 10cm rod was increased by 10% and then reduced by 10%.

Comment: But did you hear the response on the other side of the line? It was probably: 'Bahahaha they're the same you schmuck... forget about it.'

Answer (score 5):

$10\%$ of $10\text{ cm}$ *is* $1\text{ cm}$. $10\text{ cm}\times\frac{10}{100}=1\text{ cm}$.

I really don't see how this is a 'nit-pick', or 'relative' vs 'absolute', as suggested in the comments.

Are you absolutely, $100\%$, or at least relatively, sure you got the quote right? (There *are* very close variations of it, where indeed it would be rather stupid not to know the difference.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got the quote verbatim. The physics professor was walking past me in the hallway, talking on his cell phone, and said what I quoted above. When he said that, I stopped in my tracks. It immediately stuck in my head because I couldn't see the solution. I like solving problems, but this one has been bugging me non-stop.

Comment: @user3532993 I don't believe that. First of all the quote is unbelievable by itself. But secondly, I don't believe that people have such good memory or accurate perception for such occasions. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If the 10 cm was a measured value with a corresponding error estimate, then the results would be different. Suppose the bar was $10 \text{ cm} \pm 0.10 \text{ cm}$. Adding exactly $1 \text{ cm}$ to the length of the bar would yield $11 \text{ cm} \pm 0.10 \text{ cm}$, whereas increasing the length of the bar by 10% yields $11 \text{ cm} \pm 0.11 \text{ cm}$.

Nevertheless, this solution takes advantage of what is clearly a nitpicky difference, especially without being provided with a context of measurement error.

Comment: +1 If that is correct, then David Z's edit to the question might be wrong(footing). Because, for some (which?) reason, the OP suspected something related to measurement.

Comment: Just a guess but I don't think measurement accuracy was the hidden point.  I think he was looking for relative vs absolute which is a common theme in physics and in a round-about way also covers your point of tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but perhaps he actually said (or meant) "1 cubic centimeter".
Increasing the rod length by 10% is not the same as adding 1 cubic centimeter (because the rod is circular, not square, in the other dimensions).
Also assuming the diameter of the rod is 1cm.

Answer (score 2):

One thing would be that it's not practical to use '%' in that example. I can easily imagine metal worker going nuts if whole 'tech spec' is in ratios.

Aftervards you can't just decrease by 10% and get the same original length.

Or maybe because he didn't specify that it's 10% of original length.

I have this 'dejavu' feeling that I have heard something similar and there's something more.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there just is no difference. The professor would have wanted to hear

"There is no difference!"

Of course, most people being put in such a situation will assume the answer should be more elaborate and respond

"I don't know"

which seemed unsufficient from the professor's point of view.